# Publishing Deeplinks on Android

Tags: android, facebook

i am trying to get publish via my app on Facebook. So far i have been able to create an active session with the necessary permission but when i click on the share button, the Facebook dialog pops up, remains completely dark for a few seconds and the closes.

Below is the error message i was able to extract

```
01-02 15:18:07.537: W/System.err(14344): com.facebook.FacebookDialogException
01-02 15:18:07.537: W/System.err(14344):    at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog$DialogWebViewClient.onReceivedSslError(WebDialog.java:396)
01-02 15:18:07.537: W/System.err(14344):    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onReceivedSslError(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:699)
01-02 15:18:07.537: W/System.err(14344):    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.allowCertificateError(AwContentsClientBridge.java:61)
01-02 15:18:07.537: W/System.err(14344):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
01-02 15:18:07.537: W/System.err(14344):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
01-02 15:18:07.537: W/System.err(14344):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-02 15:18:07.537: W/System.err(14344):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-02 15:18:07.537: W/System.err(14344):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-02 15:18:07.547: W/System.err(14344):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 15:18:07.547: W/System.err(14344):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 15:18:07.547: W/System.err(14344):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-02 15:18:07.547: W/System.err(14344):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-02 15:18:07.547: W/System.err(14344):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 15:18:07.577: W/chromium(14344): [WARNING:aw_contents_client_bridge.cc(83)] Ignoring unexpected ssl error proceed callback
```

my Publish code is as follows

```
    private void facebookFeedDialog() {
    // Set the dialog parameters
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "xxxxx");
    params.putString("caption", xxxx);
    params.putString("description", "check this room out");
    params.putString("link", "http://xxxxxxx.com");
    params.putString("picture", null);
    // Invoke the dialog
    WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(RoomPage.this,
            fSession, params)).setOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method
                    // stub
                    if (error == null) {
                        // When the story is posted,
                        // echo the
                        // success
                        // and the post Id.
                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                        if (postId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(RoomPage.this,
                                    "Story published: " + postId,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Generic, ex: network error
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(
                                RoomPage.this,
                                "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }

                }

            }).build();

    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: can you post your publish code?

Comment: This looks like an SSL error that's happening in the webview. Are you on an actual device, or emulator? Do you have the date set correctly?

Comment: yes am on an actual device